# Should I use haproxy's "linux2628" or "linux26" make target?

Tags: linux, haproxy

With the latest versions of HAProxy, simply typing `make` does not work, returning the following message:

> Due to too many reports of suboptimized setups, building without
>   specifying the target is no longer supported. Please specify the
>   target OS in the TARGET variable, in the following form:
>
> make TARGET=xxx
>
> Please choose the target among the following supported list :
>
> linux2628, linux26, linux24, linux24e, linux22, solaris    freebsd,
>   openbsd, cygwin, custom, generic
>
> Use "generic" if you don't want any optimization, "custom" if you want
>   to precisely tweak every option, or choose the target which matches
>   your OS the most in order to gain the maximum performance out of it.
>   Please check the Makefile in case of doubts.

What is the difference between `linux2628` and `linux26` ? Can I use `linux2628` even if I have a newer kernel version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you may use `linux2628`.

From the `gmane.comp.web.haproxy` mailing list (taken from `1.5-dev11`'s changelog)

```
- added a build target "linux2628" which is like linux26 but automatically
includes splicing and tproxy.
```